# Related to AR core for my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, arcore, android-augmented-reality, pub.dev

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':arcore_flutter_plugin' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

// in my android build.gradle file the  ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0' with this it show me error when i change the kotlin version 1.5.20 it give me error too  i dont why can any solve this problem

i tried alot to solve this error i tried every steps which is given on youtube chat gpt but i didnt solve it